# Python installed on raspberry pi, but not accessible in /usr/local/bin

Tags: python, installation, pip, raspberry-pi

When I enter
`python --version`
it gives:

*bash: python: command not found*

but when I enter
`sudo apt-get install python`
it gives:

*python is already the newest version (2.7.16-1).*

When trying to `locate` the python files, they appear mostly in **/var/lib/dpkg/info/** or in **/home/pi/.local/bin/**, therefore are present in the system, however they do not appear where they would normally be found in **/usr/local/bin**.
The same thing goes for the pip, python3 and pip3 files.
How do I fix this so that I can use the python command?

Comment: Include ```/home/pi/.local/bin``` in your pi user's PATH statement.

Answer (score 1):

To install python to the newest version run `sudo apt-get install python3`

You then need to run `python3` for linux based systems so `python3 --version` should work.